# Pipenv - Failed creating virtual environment - Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, windows-10

I am desperately trying to fix what I think is a broken installation of Python3 on Windows 10. Initially, I was using Atom editor and running code by using the python command in Powershell. I installed Python3 using the default settings in the Chocolatey package manage for Windows.

Later on I started getting a weird error message in my scripts complaining about the module webdriver not being installed.

I haphazardly began uninstalling and reinstalling software. Eventually I did the best I could to remove everything and using the Python3 executable to perform a clean installation. I started this tutorial on performing a proper installation of Python3 on Windows.

When I arrived to the section on Pipenv and Virtual Environments, I started getting a similar error message complaining about webdriver not being installed.

This is very frustrating. I've tried doing a clean installation, removing variable paths, deleting folders and such. But as far as I can tell Python is broken on my Windows machine and I don't know how to fix it.

```
C:\Users\PineAppleUser\Desktop\webproject> pipenv install --trusted-host=pypi.org --trusted-host=files.pythonhosted.org requests
Creating a virtualenv for this project…
Pipfile: C:\Users\PineAppleUser\Desktop\webproject\Pipfile
Using c:\python38\python.exe (3.8.2) to create virtualenv…
[==  ] Creating virtual environment...ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webdriver'

Failed creating virtual environment
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:   File "C:\Users\PineAppleUser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pipenv\cli\command.py", line 235, in install
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:       retcode = do_install(
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:   File "C:\Users\PineAppleUser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 1734, in do_install
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:       ensure_project(
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:   File "C:\Users\PineAppleUser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 570, in ensure_project
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:       ensure_virtualenv(
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:   File "C:\Users\PineAppleUser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 505, in ensure_virtualenv
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:       do_create_virtualenv(
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:   File "C:\Users\PineAppleUser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 934, in do_create_virtualenv
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:       raise exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException(
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:
Failed to create virtual environment.
C:\Users\PineAppleUser\Desktop\webproject>
```

Comment: you may have `webdriver` in your Pipfile and need to remove it.

Comment: Many people find that conda https://conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html offers a more reliable development environment, in part because installing an env installs a new version of python for you.